# ImportError: cannot import name Weather even though i had installed the weather-api

Tags: python, linux, api, import, weather-api

I'm pretty new to this so please excuse my ignorance I'm trying my best to catch up and understand all the information out there.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "weather.py", line 1, in <module>
    from weather import Weather, Unit
  File "/home/kumyl/Documents/Projects/Weather-api-test/weather.py", line 1, in <module>
    from weather import Weather, Unit
ImportError: cannot import name Weather
```

This is the error I get when I do python weather.py or python3 weather.py. Not sure why that's happening. I looked online and found I needed to update pip, I have done that: pip --version gives me

```
pip 19.0.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

I think that's up to date? I don't really know the issue here. Some solutions said to make a virtual environment to run python? Not too sure what that is either so any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It seems that `weather` does not exist in your packages, have you tried to install it with `pip install weather`?

Comment: I had done that, it turned out the issue was I named my python file the same as my source file which imported from my own file first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

python will try to import from your script first because it has the same name 'weather.py'.
You should change the name of your file to a different one and it should work.